# issue with my wp site after login

Tags: login

I'm seeing an odd issue with my wp site. The problem is that it works fine locally but some people report seeing it at their side.

They report that after a login the navigation bar shows that they are still logged out. This problem gets solved once I ask them to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any caching plugin on the website? If yes then try disabling it and see if the issue occurs again. If you use Cloudflare, try disabling that as well temporarily.

If the issue is because of the cache, then try disabling/tweaking some of its option to see what exactly is causing this issue.

Comment: Hi Afnan, 
1. No I'm not using any caching plugin. 
2. No Cloudflare is not installed in my Plugin.
3. I have try to tweak some options and google it but still didn't success. 

i I disable the .htaccess will it damage my site?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by disabling the Cache from Host-provider.